# How to avoid the second view ( presentation of my app ) after login for the second time and go to the menu?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, segue

I created three view controller :

1. log In
2. presentation of my app
3. menu

I want the user go to the menu after log in for the second time in my app instead of seeing again the presentation of my app

I came up with this solution : when the user press a button (anyone) on menu, it's mean second time in my app

1. I created a segue identifier : secondTimeLogin between log in and menu
2. in my first view controller (login) I created this code :

```js
if let user = user {
                  
                    if let pressMenu = user["userClickedInMenu"] {
                        
                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("secondTimeLogin", sender: self)
                        
                    } else {
            
                      
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("presentationScreen", sender: self)
                    }
```

It's doesn't work for me

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create 2 segues with the identifiers: `"loginToPresentation"` and `"loginToMenu"`. As their names suggest, `"loginToPresentation"` segues from login view to presentation view, and `"loginToMenu"` segues from login view to menu view. Those are in addition to the segue from presentation view to menu view.
2. Save a bool in [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/) like `"previouslyLoggedIn"` and set it to `TRUE` the first time the user logs in. You'll know whether or not it is the first time by querying `NSUserDefaults` every time at login. If you get `FALSE` for your boolean, then this is the first time the user logs in so you need to 1. set your boolean to `TRUE` and 2. `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginToPresentation", sender: self)`. If you get `TRUE` for your boolean, then this isn't the first time the user logs in so you just go straight to menu view `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginToMenu", sender: self)`.

   Here's how your code from step 2 should look like:

   ```
   let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
   if defaults.boolForKey("previouslyLoggedIn")
   {
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginToMenu", sender: self)
   }
   else
   {
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginToPresentation", sender: self)
       defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "previouslyLoggedIn")
   }
   ```

   This should be part of your handling of a successful login.

Comment: where can I put the NSUserDefaults, I'm new in swift.. in log in or menu, and where exactly ?

Comment: @Ahmed Attention, what he is asking is not to skip the login but skip the presentation window after login to jump to a scond view controller if I don't understand wrong. :-)

Comment: @MamounMK In login. This goes as part of handling a successful login because you need this to determine where you're going next (presentation or menu).

Comment: @Lorenzo Sure that's what I understood from his question and my steps should allow him to do exactly that. Thanks for the clarification though!!

Comment: But like what @Lorenzo said, If the second time the user use my app go to the menu (even he didn't log in ) because I have a button with skip log in, so in that case it's different

Comment: With this solution, the first time the user uses the app, they will go through `login --> presentation --> menu`. The second time (and after) the user uses the app, they will go through `login --> menu`. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "previouslyLoggedIn") where do I have to put this part @AhmedHamed ?

Comment: Yes exactly ! @AhmedHamed

Comment: if let previouslyLoggedIn = true {
                        
                        
                       
                        
                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("secondTimeLogin", sender: self)
                        
                    } else {
                    
                 // please watch the video 141 from rob for letting user create their own VS after registration 
 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginToPresentation", sender: self)
  }

Comment: @MamounMK you put this where you handle a successful login. I'll update my answer with some code

Comment: Thanks @AhmedHamed ! can you check my code below, I post my code with your code! but still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

After the first presentation with success, save something in a file (or in some defaultettings) just to remember to skip the presentation page at the second time. Every time you run the application you should read the file (or default settings) to see if is necessary to skip or not the presetantion page or not. In this case you can save in a file the username of the user and the date time so you can control a sort of "timeout" session for the user. I think this can help you. You can apply also the same system to avoid the login for the same user in a small period.

Comment: I don't want to skip the login page but the second page, and when the user  press a button in the third page, it will redirect him directly from log in to the menu and skip my presentation page

Comment: That's why I created a button in the last view controler (menu) when he click on anywhere on this page it's mean it was he second time.. but what do you mean in defaultsetting ? I'm new in swift thanks

Comment: But if you close and open the app do you loose the information?

Comment: Normally I use objective-c and in my case I use [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:xxx . You can use the UserDefault setting to store permanently in the device small info about your App. In this case you can save a flag "skipPresetation". You can save number, string, boolean and so...

Comment: that's what I don't want haha ! That's why I don't know if in that case my solution will not work, but your solution with the time, it will be a good one, but I don't know how to perform that ...

Comment: Seccar for NSUserdefault in the Apple documentation or here in StackOverflow. I'm sure you will fine info about it. You have only to save something in the device. You can also save an empty text file instead and look if the file exist to skip the presentation

Comment: Oh I see, I have to do some research on swift with NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults, to integrate that in my code ! do you have an idea ?

Comment: Look here https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/12/2/reading-and-writing-basics-nsuserdefaults I'm sure can help you

Comment: let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setInteger(25, forKey: "Age"),  in my case will be a button in menu instead of age , how to integrate that ? and where thanks for ur help !

Comment: It could be NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() defaults.setInteger(1, forKey: "SkipIntro") –

Comment: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() defaults.setInteger(1, forKey: "SkipIntro") where do i have to integrate this code ? on  class ViewController: UIViewController { }?

Comment: I don't understand very well your code but could be something like:  if "skipIntro" is 1 then perform segue "secondviewcontroller" else perform segue "presentation". I think you can put this in the login page where you decide to open the presentation or the second view

Comment: When you find a solution please upvote and confirm the best answer ok? Pleasure to help you. Bye

Comment: You can also use more than one Settings to define the behaviour of your segue: You can save a setting for "Skip intro" and one for "Skip Login"